# How to fetch a part of string upto a chracter?

Tags: oracle10g

I want to fetch the names of employees from a table upto the character '**:**' but couldn't as substr and ltrim is not working as expected. Below given are given some examples:

```
    ABINERI:REBECCA C
    CARRINGTON:JAMES M
```

But I want them in the way given below:

```
    REBECCA C ABINERI
    JAMES M CARRINGTON
```

I just used the query below in Toad for Oracle:

```
<pre>
<b>select name from employees</b>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below query:

```
select SUBSTR(name,(INSTR(name,':')+1)) || ' ' || SUBSTR(name,1,(INSTR(name,':'))-1) from employees;
```

hope above query will resolve your issue.